# How to create a calculated field that counts number of unique jobs in SFMC Intelligence (Datorama) Analytics

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, analytics, datorama, sfmc-datorama

Within Intelligence (Datorama) analytics in SFMC, there is a way create calculated fields.

Default fields support total email sends but there is no field / dimension for total emails (i.e. Job ID). I know I can get the number via sql but would like to get it in reporting area so anyone can use the field.

How to create a calculated field to get breakdown of number of emails (i.e. jobids) so I can present the number per/month?

Answer (score 0):

there's a countdistinct function: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_dat_calc_measurement_functions.htm&type=5

> COUNT  COUNTDISTINCT([dimensions], [groupByDims])  Returns the number of unique appearances of dimension value combinations within the supplied context dimensions. If no groupBy dimensions are supplied, the row context is used.

if you have access to use calculated measurements -- available in either standalone MCI or advanced Intelligence Reports

Comment: In this case, is it going to be a calculated measurement with this formula? COUNTDISTINCT([Send Job ID]) OR COUNTDISTINCT([Email Content Name]) ?